# PathMeasure in Android

Tags: android, path, measure

Now I am learning how to use pathmeasure in android. I have 3 paths:`entryPath`,`leftPath` and `rightPath`.When I want to add these paths into a pathmeasure,I tried this:

```
    mTickPath.addPath(entryPath);
    mTickPath.addPath(leftPath);
    mTickPath.addPath(rightPath);
    mTickMeasure = new PathMeasure(mTickPath, false);
    // mTickMeasure is a PathMeasure
```

However I got a problem where I have `mTickMeasure.getLenth()` being equal to the entryPath.`mTickPath` is not the same as `entryPath` I have used `canvas.drawPath(mTickPath,paint)` and I get their paths on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PathMeasure.getLength()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure.html#getLength%28%29) returns only length of the current contour (in this case, entryPath). [PathMeasure.nextContour()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure.html#nextContour%28%29) will move to the next contour, or return false if it was the last.

Total length of the path can be computed by adding lengths of all contours.